# How to send Json containing xml value from POSTMAN?

Tags: json, postman

I am using postman to test api. The method is POST and JSON data is:

`{  "page" : "<xml> <content xs="xyz">.......</xml>"  }`

In body I have selected 'raw' and selected 'JSON' which automatically adds 'application/json' to the header.

When I send this request, I get error due to the double quotes in the `<content> tag`. Does this need handling (escaping) at input or inside the api code?

Comment: Could you please add sample data to the question?

Comment: can you please some more info, or in postman, you need to change Media type, go to Body tab, select Raw, and select json,

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape double quotes with \, e.g.

```
{"page":"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<page></page>"}
```

Also make sure you set HTTP header Content-Type: application/json.